# Randomize order of two columns per row in a query

Tags: mysql, sql, random

I want to copy rows from one MySQL table to another while randomizing the order of two fields, i.e. I want to take rows with the fields `id`,`a`,`b` from `table1` and insert them into `table2`, but swap `a` and `b` on random rows.

This is what I tried:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, a, b)
  SELECT
    id,
    IF(@r=RAND() < 0.5, a, b),
    IF(@r        < 0.5, b, a)
  FROM table1
  WHERE table1.filter = 42;
```

I expected that this will generate one random number per row, but it actually just generates one random number per query, so it's either a,b for all rows or b,a for all rows. What do I need to change?

---

P.S: I'm using a variable because calling `rand()` in both IFs will generate two seperate numbers and I could get the same field twice. Is there a way to to this without a variable?

Comment: what is datatype of a and b?

Comment: SMALLINT UNSIGNED

Comment: it works if you change `=` to `:=` and move the assignment outside (i.e. `SELECT @r := RAND() < 0.5, IF(@r < 0.5, a, b), ...`) but I don't know why it works that way. `RAND()` ***is*** evaluated per row.

Comment: Let the select write out `@r` and You will see the problem :-) (Hint - add parenthesis - `(@r:=RAND()) < 0.5`).

Comment: Oh yes... Salman is right of course about `:=` but once I corrected that, the results puzzled me even more. As Roman hinted, `@r=rand()<0.5` needs paranthesis around the assignment, otherwise the result will be reversed

Comment: Setting & reading the same variable in a select statement is undefined behaviour. Also, there is no guarantee that a function that is called in a query is called more than one no matter how many calls appear. The language is just not defined to behave the way you (or the current answers) are (unjustifiably) expecting. Indeed why do you think you can expect what you do?

Comment: The [documentation re nondeterministic functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/function-optimization.html) is unclear, incomplete & contradictory. It says a call in a `where` is executed once per row that is the result of the `from`. But it also says that if it determines a row is filtered out by other aspects of the `where` condition (eg index use) then it might not execute it, which is a contradiction. And it doesn't address calls in a select clause. You may want to loop in a procedure. Beware `order by rand()` has big performance problems.

Comment: Re read & write of a variable someone at Percona wrote in an answer to a question that *for the current code* they found an idiom using `case` that can read & write the same one in a statement with well-defined behaviour. (But I can't find that post.) The [documention on variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) seems to be *trying* to say there's some kind of assumptions you can make about calls in `select` but it's not clear either. (It says something about when rows are returned to the client, but *that's* not defined.) And they also say don't do it. Idiotic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using @variables seems to work but MySQL [discourages assigning and reading values to variables inside same statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) because:

> ... the order of evaluation for expressions involving user variables
>   is undefined.

A better solution is as follows:

```
-- INSERT INTO ...
SELECT
  id,
  IF(r < 0.5, a, b),
  IF(r < 0.5, b, a)
FROM (
  SELECT id, a, b, RAND() AS r
  FROM table1
  WHERE table1.filter = 42
) x
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (id, a, b)
set @r=0;
  SELECT
    id,
    IF(@r=RAND() < 0.5, a, b),
    IF(@r        < 0.5, b, a)
  FROM table1
  WHERE table1.filter = 42;
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.